# Get Dropdown value dynamically row wise

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
<select class="form-control demo-select2-placeholder" name="company" id="company">
<option value="">{{ ('Select Your Company') }}</option>
  @foreach (\App\Company::all() as $company)
     <option value="{{ $company->id }}">
          {{ $company->company_name }}
     </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

/* function written */

```
<script>
$('#company').change(function(){
   var companyID = $(this).val();
   window.alert(companyID);
 });
</script>
```

[How do I derive value from the dropdown for every row, Now the drop-down works only for the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVKVA.png)

Comment: Please add more detail to this question. What is the error? What actions are you taking to reproduce the issue? What additional debugging information can you include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one select has the id **#company** so you could try to target each select[name="company"] instead.

So change your jQuery selector to:

```
<script>
$('select[name="company"]').change(function(){
   var companyID = $(this).val();
   window.alert(companyID);
});
</script>
```